# for loop condition evaluation

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have this HTML code

```
<div id="first">
  <div id="second">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to append a child to each existing div.

When I use this code

```
function appendC() {
  var divsVar = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

  for (var i = 0; i < divsVar.length; i++) {
    var new_div = document.createElement("div");
    div[i].appendChild(new_div);
  }
}
```

the function it goes into an infinite loop. But I can't understand why.

When the function is called, it assigns to var `divsVar` an array with 2 divs in my example. Never executed again, unless I call again the function. But the divsVar.length is changed in every loop. How is this possible?? The `divsVar.length` should stay as constant??

If I use a temp variable like that

```
 function appendC() {
      var divsVar = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var _temp = divsVar.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < _temp; i++) {
        var new_div = document.createElement("div");
        div[i].appendChild(new_div);
      }
    }
```

it work like a charm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getElementsByTagName("\*") always updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271598/getelementsbytagname-always-updated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns an object containing a live `HTMLCollection`. This is updated whenever you update the dom. In your for loop, after every iteration, the `length` property is evaluated again on the current dom. 
Because you are adding divs to the dom, this loop will run forever.

The reason this works with a `_temp` variable is because you only evaluate the length of the `HTMLCollection` once.

I think the best solution would be to evaluate the length beforehand, just like your last example.

Answer (score 4):

The `.getElementsByTagName()` method returns a live `HTMLCollection`.

You can either turn the collection into an array (e.g. `[].slice.call(collection)`), or use another method such as `.querySelectorAll()` which returns a static `NodeList`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName() method returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.`

This means that even though you're not calling it again, it's still being updated. To fix this simply use

`document.querySelectorAll("div")`

which returns`A non-live NodeList containing one Element object for each element that matches at least one of the specified selectors.`